# How to keep websocket connection while entering background in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, websocket, uikit

i'm implementing real-time chat using websocket protocol.

It uses the apple websocket framework to keep the connection with the server,

but when it enters the background, the connection is disconnected.

I want to keep connection even if it enters the background.

```
   private var websocket: URLSessionWebSocketTask?

func connectWebsocket() {
   let session = URLSession(
            configuration: .default,
            delegate: self,
            delegateQueue: OperationQueue()
        )
        
        let url = URL(string: "ws://URL...")
        
        webSocket = session.webSocketTask(with: url)
        webSocket?.resume()
}
```

I want to keep connection even if it enters the background.

Is there any way to keep the connection alive?

Comment: No. There is no way to keep a socket connected when your app is suspended. You can use push notifications to send notifications of new messages.

Comment: So, is it better not to use websocket protocols in apps?

Comment: You can, but you need to be aware that you can only make the connection when your app is in the foreground.